# Can the if / else inside the for loop be converted/simplified to Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the below piece of code. I need to convert into java 8.
I tried my luck , but was stuck with else part.
Kindly help me if this could be achieved.

```
    List<String> modelValues = new ArrayList<>();
    modelValues.add("one");
    modelValues.add("two");
    modelValues.add("three");

    List<String> selectedValues = new ArrayList<>(); //Orignally fetched from the database
    selectedValues.add("four");
    selectedValues.add("five");
    selectedValues.add("six");

    for (String value : modelValues) {
        if (isSelected(value)) { //isSelected returns true or false
            selectedValues.add(value);
        } else {
            if (isNotSelected(value)) { //isNotSelected returns true or false
                selectedValues.remove(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This for-loop sounds good, just keep it.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the existence of `isNotSelected` when `isSelected` already exists.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca especially when the caller seems to assume that the `isNotSelected` still is necessary when `isSelected` already returned `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    modelValues.stream().filter(this::isSelected).forEach(selectedValues::add);
    modelValues.stream().filter(this::isNotSelected).forEach(selectedValues::remove);
```

Not the best choice since u go twice through the for loop. I would stick to you original loop.

```
modelValues.forEach(value -> {
        if (isSelected(value)) { // isSelected returns true or false
            selectedValues.add(value);
        } else if (isNotSelected(value)) { // isNotSelected returns true or false
            selectedValues.remove(value);
        }   
    });
```

Comment: Not fancy enough. How about `modelValues.stream() .<Consumer<List<String>>>map(s -> isSelected(s)? l -> l.add(s): isNotSelected(s)? l -> l.remove(s): l->{}) .forEach(op -> op.accept(selectedValues));`. *That’s* “conversion to Java 8”…

Comment: @Holger that's "descent into madness", if you ask me :)

Comment: @Holger you made my day ;)